# RDBMS: Generating a locally Unique Key for a Relational Table with Foreign Key

Tags: sql

Below is the schema of the database.

[image: database schema]

1. There are multiple screenplays each identified by a globally unique key.
2. Multiple scenes can exist for a screenplay and linked by foreign key.

The obvious choice for me for **scene_id** of Scene table was to use an auto-increment Integer field type which will ensure each scene in Scene table has a globally unique key across all the multiple screenplays.

Now, the query is:

1. What is the best way for generating **scene_id** for Scene table?
2. Isn't keeping a globally unique key an overkill when the
   **scene_id** needs to be unique only within a particular Screenplay?

A sample table

```
+----------+------------+-----------------+------+
| Scene_Id | Scene_Name |     Scrn_ID     |      |
+----------+------------+-----------------+------+
|        1 |            | Opening Scene   | 1001 |
|        2 |            | Climax Scene    | 1001 |
|        3 |            | End Credits     | 1001 |
|        1 |            | Opening Scene 1 | 1002 |
|        2 |            | Character Intro | 1002 |
|        3 |            | Conflict        | 1002 |
|        4 |            | Climax Scene    | 1002 |
+----------+------------+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: 'Isn't keeping a globally unique key an overkill when...' - not in my opinion given that you would have to code the alternative yourself and that the alternative confers no discernible advantage.

Comment: Mysql and postgresql are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use! Or if you want to ask a general question, then add general rdbms tag back.

Comment: A globally unique `screen_id` is way more efficient than a "local" one - regardless of the actual DBMS being used

Answer (score 2):

Using an automatically generated primary key is actually the *simplest* solution:

```
scene_id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

There is very little overhead in this.

It would be much more complicated and expensive to use numbers that are relative to `scm_id` – see the many questions for such a feature on this forum.

Keep it simple!